# django-autocomplete-light error = 'list' object has no attribute 'queryset'

Tags: python, django, django-autocomplete-light

i am new on django and i need your help, trying since many days to understand django-autocomplete-light, after setup my test,
http://192.168.0.108:8000/country-autocomplete/ work, data is showed like explaned here http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#overview

But after following next step, i am getting error:

```
AttributeError at /auto
'list' object has no attribute 'queryset'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://192.168.0.108:8000/auto
Django Version: 1.10.3
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:'list' object has no attribute 'queryset'
Exception Location: /home/alcall/ENV/lib/python3.4/site-packages/dal/widgets.py in filter_choices_to_render, line 161
```

Below my setup:

urls:

```
from dal import autocomplete
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from rates.view.index import *
from rates.view.index import UpdateView

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(
    r'^country-autocomplete/$',
    CountryAutocomplete.as_view(),
    name='country-autocomplete',
),
url(r'^auto$',
    UpdateView.as_view(),
    name='select',
),
]
```

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class Country(models.Model):
    enabled = models.IntegerField()
    code3l = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=3)
    code2l = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=2)
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=64)
    name_official = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    prix = models.FloatField()
    flag_32 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    flag_128 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=8,     blank=True,$
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=8, blank=True$
    zoom = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'country'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

view   (include form too)

```
from dal import autocomplete
from django.shortcuts import render
from rates.models import Country
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django import forms
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
       # if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        #    return Country.objects.none()

        qs = Country.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs

class Form_country(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Country
       fields = ('name', 'code2l')
       widgets = {
          'name': autocomplete.ModelSelect2Multiple(
            'country-autocomplete'
           )
       }

class UpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Country
    form_class = Form_country
    template_name = 'fr/public/monformulaire.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('select')


    def get_object(self):
        return Country.objects.first()
```

Comment: Please verify the code you have shared. It does not look right. - Example, the `url` pattern targets `autos` , but your `url` is just `auto`

Comment: i change it from r'^autos?$  to r'^auto$', still same issu

Comment: Post full traceback please

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue. The problem here is with the widget. Tried to fix it for very long. The only way in worked for me was changing form's widget.

If it doesn't matter that much you can use `autocomplete.ListSelect2` instead, it worked for me.

So try this:

```
class Form_country(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model = Country
       fields = ('name', 'code2l')
       widgets = {
          'name': autocomplete.ListSelect2(
            'country-autocomplete'
           )
       }
```

Actually you can just try any other autocomplete widget and see weather it works

Answer (score 3):

I you create the widget in `__init__()`, then this work-around of [issue #790](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/790#issuecomment-276309980) helps:

```
form.fields['name'].widget.choices = form.fields['name'].choices
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation, where I used it to suggest similar names that are already present in a model

**IMPORTANT: After you must have done all these, don't forget to run `python manage.py collectstatic`.**
Also note that you wish to include a `placeholder` in your form field you have to do it with `data-placeholder` in the widget `autocomplete` widget.

When you run it, you'll see this message

> Found another file with the destination path
>   'admin/js/jquery.init.js'. It will be ignored since only the first
>   encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure
>   every static file has a unique path.

This is the reason the documentation states [here](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/install.html#configuration) that you must place `dal` and `dal_select2` before `django.contrib.admin` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    stable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

`views.py`

```
from django.db.models import Q
from dal import autocomplete

class NewName(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    """Suggest similar names in form"""
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = People.objects.filter(stable=True)
        if self.q:
            query = Q(name__contains=self.q.title()) | Q(name__contains=self.q.lower()) | Q(name__contains=self.q.upper())
            qs = qs.filter(query)
        return qs
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('new-name/', views.NewName.as_view(), name='new_name_autocomplete'),
]
```

`forms.py`

```
class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = ["stable", "name"]

        widgets = {
            "name" : autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url=reverse_lazy('new_name_autocomplete'), attrs={'class' : 'form-control', 'data-placeholder' : "Name"}),
```

I had to modify `dal/widgets.py` and comment out the queryset filtering as shown below. It seems to be a bug or something. The issue has been raised [here](https://github.com/yourlabs/django-autocomplete-light/issues/790). But if you're using
`autocomplete.ListSelect2()` as your widget, then there's no need for that.

```
class QuerySetSelectMixin(WidgetMixin):
    """QuerySet support for choices."""

    def filter_choices_to_render(self, selected_choices):
        """Filter out un-selected choices if choices is a QuerySet."""
        # self.choices.queryset = self.choices.queryset.filter(
        #     pk__in=[c for c in selected_choices if c]
        # )
```