# How to use django-autocomplete-light on form with multiple charfields

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I have installed `django-autocomplete-light`.

My **form without autocomplete** looks like this:

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
    form_origin = forms.CharField(label='From country',
                                  max_length=100,
                                  required=False,
                                  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                      'placeholder': 'From country',
                                      'arial-label':'C2',
                                  }))
    form_target = forms.CharField(label='To country',
                                  max_length=100,
                                  required=False,
                                  widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                      'placeholder': 'To country',
                                      'arial-label': 'C1',
                                  }))
```

I have written **a view** following the [instructions here](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html), which gives all the countries which start with the same letter as my input.

```
class CountryAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView): 
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Country.objects.all()
        qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)
        return qs
```

However, I am having issues with using it with the form, which has two char fields, both to use the same model called `Country`. The tutorial isn't tailored to that. In essence, I hope to have two text boxes, with autocomplete of the country to and from, a bit like skyscanner. Any advice to the right direction is appreciated!

My **model** looks like this:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    iso3 = models.CharField('3 Digit ISO', max_length=3, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50)
    lon = models.FloatField()
    lat = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**UPDATE:**

My url is this:

`re_path(r'^country-autocomplete/$', views.CountryAutocomplete.as_view(), name='country-autocomplete'),`

I've updated my form to this, following help from Sumit:

```
    form_origin = forms.CharField(label='From country',
                                  max_length=100,
                                  required=False,
                                  widget=autocomplete.ListSelect2(
                                      url='myapp:country-autocomplete',
                                  ))
```

However I get a dropdown where there are no selectable fields:

I am using bootstrap and my template looks like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
     <div class="form-inline form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                  {{ field|attr:"class:form-control" }}
             </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

What does your form with autocomplete look like? Or do you not have it in there yet? If you dont then you can try it like this:

```
form_origin = forms.CharField(label='From country',
                                  max_length=100,
                                  required=False,
                                  widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='YOUR_APP_NAME:CountryAutocomplete'))
```

Do the same thing for destination also.

Also, in URL.py name sure it is declared like:

```
path('CountryAutocomplete/', views.CountryAutocomplete.as_view(), name = 'CountryAutocomplete'),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have tried using the solution, and also added the url. However I got an error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'queryset'`. I followed this instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822373/django-autocomplete-light-error-list-object-has-no-attribute-queryset). Now I simply have two dropdown boxes with no selectable content.

Comment: have you done everything else that @chidimo said in his comment on 2018 like placing dal and dal_select2 on top of all other apps? I did not have to do the change he suggested to widgets.py so try it without trying that one.